# Create table with variable number of columns

Tags: vba, excel

I am hoping to get a few ideas for something to push me in the right direction. I have a custom class that stores data from a table based on criteria. The raw data (consisting of over 100 columns and varying between 10-1000 rows) is on a worksheet. My code does the following:

> 1 - Creates an object from the custom class
>   2 - Adds a value to the properties of the object
>   3 - Adds the object to a collection
>   4 - Returns the collection to the controller which sends it to the view to build the table

The following will build a collection of column ranges from the raw data, at least:

```
Private mcolColumnAddresses As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()   
    Set mcolColumnAddresses = New Collection
    Dim vHeader As Variant
    For Each vHeader In mwksReport.Range(mwksReport.Cells(1, 1), mwksReport.Cells(1, mlLastColumn))
        mcolColumnAddresses.Add vHeader.Offset(1, 0).Resize(mlLastRow - 1), vHeader.value
    Next vHeader
End Sub
```

The end users want the ability to choose the columns they want for building the new table. But a typical class for a table would use a row as an object with the column headers as the properties. How would I build a table using class properties when the columns are not known until run-time? I hope that makes sense.

*Note*: I am not asking for code but for suggestions. Has anybody else had this requirement? If so, how did you approach it? An example is welcome, too.

Comment: I think you would have to aim more generically for your class. A class for "Properties" like a name/value pair that your generic "Row" class could instantiate as many times as their is columns and fill. That or perhaps your "Row" class could just store the properties (column header and value) in a dictionary?

Comment: Whiteboard design questions are usually better suited for [softwareengineering.se]. Please review their /help/on-topic page to make sure it's on-topic before posting there though.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Oh! I had no idea. I guess it can be closed in keeping with the votes.

Comment: @Brian: I think your question could be on-topic here as well as on SE, but since you already deleted your crossposted question there, just let it here.

Comment: ... first you wrote *"I have a custom class"*, and then *"a typical class for a table would use a row as an object with the column headers as the properties"* - so what do you actually have implemented so far, and what is only on your whiteboard?

Comment: @DocBrown I don't have a whiteboard, which is probably my first mistake. I still consider myself a rookie developer (self taught). What I have implemented is an `agenda` class with five read/write properties. In a `model` class I use VBA functions to get the value for each property before adding the `agenda` class object to the collection. Then I send the collection to the controller which sends it to the view to build the new table. So my `model` class is the raw data and my `agenda` class is the table I am building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But a typical class for a table would use a row as an object with the column headers as the properties

If your table has really more than 100 columns, or if the column names are only known a runtime, you should probably approach this different. One object per row is fine, but your class could provide a method for accessing all column values by their name. In VBA syntax:

```
  Function GetValue(byval columnName as string) as Variant
  '...
```

As you see, you have to sacrifice some type safety here, but that is typically a small price to pay for getting this solved in a sensible manner.

Internally, your objects can store the values in some `Dictionary` (in VBA available through the MS Scripting Runtime), indexed by the column names. This leads to

```
  Function GetValue(byval columnName as string) as Variant
      if valueDict.ContainsKey(columnName) then
           GetValue = valueDict(columnName)
      else
           '... add some error handling here
      end if
  End Function
```

For populating the dictionary, any database has possibilities to determine column names for a table, just google for " get column names programmatically" to find some example code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually already have something that does this. My `model` class initialize event populates a collection of ranges with the header value as the `key`. But each end user might choose different columns to print the table. In other words, they choose whatever columns from the raw data and create a different table. But it's not a copy/paste. The data rows of the new table are based on `CountIfs()` or `Index(Match())` criteria on the raw data. So I don't see how I can use an `Agenda` class with header properties if the columns are not known at runtime.

Comment: @Brian: I don't understand where exactly your problem is. Your program gets a list of column names from your users as strings (how exactly does not matter). Then you can use a function like the one above to query the values from the dictionary. Why do you insist on using *"an Agenda class with header properties"*? That sounds not like what I suggested.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying now. Get rid of the `Agenda` class entirely and use the collection/Dictionary object to get the column address for the VBA function. I think that answers my main question.